# Game rejected by AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, app-store

I developed a card game using cocos2D and recently uploaded its binary in the appstore.I used some CCtransition effects in the game when we move from one scene to another.The appstore rejects the binary with the reason "**when the user taps on any of the tabs at the bottom of the launch screen, a full screen transition is produced**".What can i do now?Is CCTransition,the problem?

Answer (score 8):

A tab bar should change the content that's contained in another part the page, and should not transition the tab bar itself. If your tab bar buttons fire a full-screen transition, that's a violation of the Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Good edit, @MDT. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If they think that its a violation of the Human interface Guidelines then instead of tab bar make some new design buttons and put then at bottom of your game.....:)